# ORMLite IllegalArgumentException class is not valid for type

Tags: java, android, ormlite

I am using ORMLite and I got stuck with this problem:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Field class java.lang.Integer for field
     FieldType:name=tempo_minimo,class=Servico is not valid for type
     com.j256.ormlite.field.types.IntType@9acd29f, maybe should be int
```

The class in trouble:

```
@DatabaseTable(tableName="servico")
public class Servico {
    ...

    @DatabaseField(dataType=DataType.INTEGER)
    private Integer tempo_minimo;

    public Integer getTempo_minimo() {
        return tempo_minimo;
    }

    public void setTempo_minimo(Integer tempo_minimo) {
        this.tempo_minimo = tempo_minimo;
    }

    ...
}
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Field class java.lang.Integer for field FieldType:name=tempo_minimo,class=Servico is not valid for type com.j256.ormlite.field.types.IntType@9acd29f, maybe should be int

This error message is trying to give you all of the information you need.  It is saying that it is expecting an `int` but the field actually is of type `Integer`.  I suspect you need to regenerated your [table configuration file](http://ormlite.com/docs/table-config).  You can also change the field back to being an `int` but I suspect you changed it recently from `int` to `Integer` on purpose.

Hope this helps.